# DRF CSRF cookie not set

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, postman, csrf

I have a DRF project, with an endpoint `path('api/auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),`

When sending a POST request from Postman to the endpoint `api/auth/login/`, in order to login with an existing user. I get the following error

> Forbidden (403)
> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
>
> You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms. This cookie is required for security reasons, to ensure that your browser is not being hijacked by third parties.
>
> If you have configured your browser to disable cookies, please re-enable them, at least for this site, or for “same-origin” requests.
>
> Help
> Reason given for failure:
>
> CSRF cookie not set.

I tried to set a csrf header (`X-CSRFTOKEN`, `XSRF-TOKEN`).

I also logged in with the user from the DRF API interface and found the value for X-CSRFTOKEN, which I set in Postman with no success.

I also tried to tweak many settings in `setttings.py` such as (`CSRF_COOKIE_NAME`, `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` ..

Also, to mention the POST method is working on other endpoints for creating objects.

I am so thankful if anyone would have an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending your request as a form? (using `content-type` of `multipart/form-data` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). If so, add a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` field to the data:

[image]

Comment: I tried setting csrf on the headers, and also like you mentioned, still the same result

Comment: @tnsduser outside of Postman, how are you making those calls? A single page app? Are they cross-origin? If so, did you set [`CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE) to `'None'`. Clear cookies in your browser after you change the setting